# How can i check if X number of elements with same class but different id have one specific css property identical?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i check if X number of elements with same `class` but different `id` have one specific css property identical? Imagine that there are 20 elements or somewhere like this with same class.
Like here

```
<div class="back" id="i1"></div>
<div class="back" id="i2"></div>
<div class="back" id="i3"></div>

<style>
   back{width:100px;height:100px;float:left;}
   #i1{background-image:url(img1.jpg);}
   #i2{background-image:url(img2.jpg);}
</style>
```

And if they are identical i add a class but i suppose that would be easy.
An example of what i have is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5WxQM/)

Comment: Do you have a list of all the `id`s you want to check?

Comment: What are you trying to check, exactly? If some particular css property is the same for all elements having that class?

Comment: If you have 20 elements. There are A LOT of combination of identical properties. `i1` and `i2` can have same color, `i2` and `i3` can have the same font... What do you want to know?

Comment: @AmaanCheval the ids go from 1 to 20.

Comment: This sounds like a bad way to solve a problem. What is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: i want to make a basic game. i have twenty cards face down, and when i turn them i add a class back. you can't turn more than two cards, after that they turn with face down. but if from that 20 you turn 2 card with same background image they remain 'un-turn-able'.

Comment: @DanOvidiuBoncut: Are you trying to implement a Memory game?

Comment: @Amberlamps: yes. i added a fiddle to my question.

Answer (score 1):

To test css properties you can use `.css()`, for example:

```
if ($('#i1').css('background-image') == $('#i2').css('background-image')) {
    // do something
}
```

Let's say you want to check whether all the ".back" divs have the same `background-image` (I hope it's what you're trying to achieve). You could go with something like this:

```
var same = 1;
var property = $(".back").first().css('background-image');
$(".back").each(function() {
    if ($(this).css('background-image') != property)
        same = 0;
});
if (same == 1) {  // all properties where the same 
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't really see where your going with this, but you can do something on these lines.

```
var arr = [];
$.each($('.back'), function() {
  arr.push($(this).css('background-image'));
});
```

Or maybe,

```
$.each($('.back'), function() {
    if ($(this).css('background-image') === 'lookingForThis.jpg') {
        alert('Found it!');  
}
});
```